# Issue with setting multiple projectionSchemas for AvroParquetInputFormat

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, avro, parquet

I use AvroParquetInputFormat. The usecase requires scanning of multiple input directories and each directory will have files with one schema. Since AvroParquetInputFormat class could not handle multiple input schemas, I created a workaround by statically creating multiple dummy classes like MyAvroParquetInputFormat1, MyAvroParquetInputFormat2 etc where each class just inherits from AvroParquetInputFormat. And for each directory, I set a different MyAvroParquetInputFormat and that worked (please let me know if there is a cleaner way to achieve this).

My current problem is as follows:

Each file has a few hundred columns and based on meta-data I construct a projectionSchema for each directory, to reduce unnecessary disk & network IO. I use the static setRequestedProjection() method on each of my MyAvroParquetInputFormat classes. But, being static, the last call’s projectionSchema is used for reading data from all directories, which is not the required behavior.

Any pointers to workarounds/solutions would is highly appreciated.

Thanks & Regards

MK

Answer (score 2):

Keep in mind that if your avro schemas are compatible (see avro doc for definition of schema compatibility) you can access all the data with a single schema. Extending on this, it is also possible to construct a parquet friendly schema (no unions) that is compatible with all your schemas so you can use just that one.

As for the approach you took, there is no easy way of doing this that I know of. You have to extend MultipleInputs functionality somehow to assign a different schema for each of your input formats. MultipleInputs works by setting two configuration properties in your job configuration:

```
mapreduce.input.multipleinputs.dir.formats //contains a comma separated list of InputFormat classes
mapreduce.input.multipleinputs.dir.mappers //contains a comma separated list of Mapper classes.
```

These two lists must be the same length. And this is where it gets tricky. This information is used deep within hadoop code to initialize mappers and input formats, so that's where you should add your own code.

As an alternative, I would suggest that you do the projection using one of the tools already available, such as hive. If there are not too many different schemas, you can write a set of simple hive queries to do the projection for each of the schemas, and after that you can use a single mapper to process the data or whatever the hell you want.